# A lot of Edits happening to pages mentioning "Ink"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, suggested-edits

I just noticed, when reviewing pending edits, that a user: [leesei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665507/leesei?tab=reputation), with free edit privilege (yet), has gone through and edited more than 30 posts. Most of these mention some kind of "microsoft.ink" topic.

[image: Screenshot of rep]

I don't know if something dodgy is going on, or if leesei is a subject matter expert who has decided to fix all the problems.

He has edited the tag wikis.

I'm going to assume the latter and say "What a great guy. It is through this vast amount of manual editing that this site becomes as awesome as it is" while being cautious enough to put this on Meta and ask if anyone who knows about this stuff cares to manually check that there isn't something weird going on.

So the actual question: **Are these edits legitimate?**

Comment: [That user is trying to remove that ambiguous tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215903/187824)

Comment: Ahh, Nice. I was looking for explaination on meta, but I beat him to it. (Check timestamps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these are first going through as suggested edits, and people are approving them.

Looking at a few random ones, they are primarily just retags. Based on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215903/187824), it seems the user has decided to retag these to make the 'ink' tag less ambiguous.