# Ambiguous [ink] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

I was looking for Zurb Ink and found the [[ink] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ink) clouded with many results:

- [Microsoft.Ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft.ink)
- [Zurb Ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-ink)
- [ink.sapo.pt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ink.sapo.pt)
- printer ink

I've created tags and wiki pages for the above three.
Is there any mechanism to force SO users to choose one of them instead of the generic [ink]?
Should we add info to the [ink] tag wiki?

Comment: Ha, I ran into your pile of edits and was getting worried, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215902/alot-of-edits-happening-to-pages-mentioning-ink 
Nice work, with this.

Comment: ^_^ I wanted to finish the edits before posting the meta question.

Comment: @leesei One thing about posting on Meta first though is that the visibility means you have a good chance of getting help. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our best mechanism of forcing people to use other tags is to just get rid of the ambiguous tag so only those other ones show up. The [ink](/questions/tagged/ink) tag has now been destroyed.